# Display Many Sprites in Bevy

Tags: rust, rendering, bevy

I want to write a small game using Bevy in Rust. Displaying a lot of sprites (10'000) is a problem if all of them are a separate `SpriteBundle`. How do I get one entity to contain and display several Sprites?

I am aware of [Fastest way to deal with many sprites in bevy-engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68407372/fastest-way-to-deal-with-many-sprites-in-bevy-engine).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is 2D, right? If so, are you trying to make a gird-based/tile-based game?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is in 2D. I'm trying to make a grid-based/tile-based game. For another project I also didn't manage to put Sprites and Text on the same Entities.

Comment: @Wisart Please checkout this library: https://github.com/StarArawn/bevy_ecs_tilemap#bevy_ecs_tilemap. If you need any more help, I'd strongly recommend asking on the Bevy Discord server: https://discord.gg/bevy